# How can I efficiently create a list with the figures of a number in Python?

Tags: python

I have a number and I want to create a list, each element having the figures of the aforementioned number.

As an example, I have `n=225` and I want to have the list `l=[2,2,5]`.

I can convert the number into a string, then convert the string as a list, like this:

```
l=list(str(n))
l=[int(i) for i in lst]
```

But I think there is a better way of doing it. Can you help me?

Comment: `list(map(int, str(n)))`

Comment: Worked, thanks! If you want some reputation points, write an answer.

Comment: That does it too.